# getting Can't find variable: webpackJsonp with webpack built project

Tags: webpack, webpacker

Here is my configuration (I'm using webpacker with Rails)

```
environment.entry['jquery-uls'] = [
  './node_modules/@bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
  './node_modules/@bower_components/lodash/lodash.js',
  './node_modules/@bower_components/jquery.uls/src/jquery.uls.data.js',
  './node_modules/@bower_components/jquery.uls/src/jquery.uls.data.utils.js',
  './node_modules/@bower_components/jquery.uls/src/jquery.uls.lcd.js',
  './node_modules/@bower_components/jquery.uls/src/jquery.uls.languagefilter.js',
  './node_modules/@bower_components/jquery.uls/src/jquery.uls.core.js',
];

environment.plugins.append(
  'CommonChunks',
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'jquery-uls',
    minChunks: Infinity,
  })
);
```

The error I get in the browser is:

```
ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
ReferenceError: Raven is not defined
ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
```

In research on this I understand that the issue might be caused by incorrect ordering of things, so here is the relevant part of the DOM tree.

```
<script src="/packs/raven-80435354a02573d42db2.js"></script>
<!-- / Sentry logging -->
<script>
Raven.config(SentryDsn).install();
Raven.setExtraContext(currentUser);
</script>
<script src="/assets/javascripts/jquery-uls.js"></script>
<script src="/packs/main-e5d1eff17ae48e5067be.js"></script>

<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="7YxjpYGr1Q/foPI+v4DHrSLAq9ZeD6Mfthvv6BGwG1Sq5FWReguDQdtUxW48CRbRSVinUpmKW1vHkS0tY9UobQ==">
```

Any ideas?

Comment: For anyone curious for additional context, we're trying to switch from a gulp+webpack build process to webpack+webpacker: https://github.com/WikiEducationFoundation/WikiEduDashboard/pull/1774